# How can a Artificial Neural Network be trained to find location of a match in the image

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I learned that neural networks are only good at answering Yes or No questions, such as "is this a person, is this a car, is this an apple" etc.

But I see examples of ANNs finding matches to faces of people in a crowded place and being used for traditional machine vision applications, such as sub-pixel template matching.

Is this just a product of a combination of ANN and traditional matching techniques. Such as recognizing which features are matching to a known template using an ANN, and then figuring out where those keypoints are in the image using good old image processing? Or is it possible to get something other than a Yes or a No response from a network?

Comment: They use a scrolling window, i.e. they feed to the ANN a subregion of the image at various locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get a range of answers from an Artificial Neural Network. It depends on how you set up your Neurons.

*Artificial Neural Networks make decisions by being trained using examples with known solutions, usually thousands of cases where the inputs and expected outputs are known.*

They get "trained" by recursively adjusting each Neurons weight by comparing its output to the expected output.

Your first layer of Neurons is your inputs. Your last layer is your outputs. If your last layer has 2 Neurons, then you will get one of two outputs.

There is no limit to how many inputs and outputs an Artificial Neural Network can have. Check out these diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Here is a [repository](https://github.com/brodderickrodriguez/CPP_xorNeuralNetwork) for an Artificial Neural Network I created that predicts the output of an XOR gate. Hope this helps!

Here is a truth table for an XOR gate for clarity.

[image]

[UPDATE]

To explicitly answer your question about Image Classification, I believe Artificial Neural Networks are a good approach.

Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@tifa2up/image-classification-using-deep-neural-networks-a-beginner-friendly-approach-using-tensorflow-94b0a090ccd4) I found helpful in understanding the implementation of an Image Classifier. You can also experiment with [Tenserflow](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/training-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification/) with is a GUI Neural Network application which is an intuitive approach to understating how Neural Networks work.

Comment: thanks! But can these be converted into something like pixel coordinates, or is that an ineffective strategy?

Comment: Yes I believe so, I am not an expert in Neural Networks, though. However, I believe it can be done by iterating through the images in chunks. For example, you grab a WxH image-snippet at origin (X,Y) and pass that image-snippet to the Neural Network. It would essentially scan the image for your desired object, returning true if it identified the object. I have updated my answer with a link to an article on Image Classification.

Comment: Thanks for the approval! When you get to 15 rep, please upvote my answer! I'd appreciate the support :)